# Maximum Likelihood Estimation in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, mle

In my project, I am using `GridSearchCV` in `sklearn` to exhaustively search over specified parameter values for a model to find the best possible parameter values. I just test that in RandomForestClassifier and helped me to find the best `max_depth` and `n_estimators`. Based on that, I have two questions:

1. Does `GridSearchCV` use the concept of Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) under the hood?
2. Instead of using `GridSearchCV` for every model, is there a technique that I can use to choose the best model for my dataset? I think this is under the concept of model selection but I don't know how to use it via `sklearn`.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> Does GridSearchCV use the concept of Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) under the hood?

MLE is **probabilistic** reasoning, thus it can be only applied to **probabilistic** models. GridSearchCV is not MLE based, it is a simple trick to do model selection based on direct estimation of the test error.So given a particular model, it can assign a number which represents how good it is - given many models, you can simply select the one with the biggest number (highest estimated generalization strength).

> Instead of using GridSearchCV for every model, is there a technique that I can use to choose the best model for my dataset? I think this is under the concept of model selection but I don't know how to use it via sklearn.

There are plenty, however sklearn pretty much implements only various train-test splitters (CV, random etc.); instead you might want to consider other libraries that support:

- Bayesian optimization
- Tree of Parzen Estimators technique

Which are more advanced methods of looking for good hyperparamters (rather than just checking already existing ones).